# Does ssh service stop on reboot?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, reboot, openssh

When I reboot a VM (Ubuntu 16.04) of mine, I'm no longer able to ssh to it. From what I understand, 'apt-get install openssh' gives you sshservice on startup by default so I'm guessing this isn't the reason.

Does anybody have any thoughts as to what the problem might be?

Comment: How are you trying to connect and authenticate (password? keys?) and what happens exactly (connection refused? times out? fails to authenticate?). Have you tried running the SSH client in verbose mode to see where it fails?

Comment: @steeldriver I am using putty and I get a Network Error: Connection timed out error. Not sure how to run verbose mode, can you explain how?

Comment: Maybe : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109934/ssh-server-stops-working-after-reboot-caused-by-missing-var-run-sshd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I figured out that the network device was simply deactivated. Weird that it deactivated upon reboot but after I could ssh I rebooted to see if the problem would occur again and it didn't.